# Proof of $\lfloor 6n \rfloor + \lfloor n \rfloor \ge 2\lfloor 2n \rfloor + \lfloor 3n \rfloor$.

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification

I used this proof to this : $\displaystyle \frac{6n!n!}{2n!2n!3n!} \in \mathbb{Z}$.

**My proof:**

> $$\displaystyle \lfloor x+y\rfloor \ge \lfloor x \rfloor + \lfloor y \rfloor$$

$$\lfloor 6x \rfloor \ge 2\lfloor3x\rfloor$$, so $$\lfloor 6x \rfloor + \lfloor x\rfloor \ge 2\lfloor3x\rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor =\lfloor3x\rfloor +\lfloor x \rfloor +\lfloor 4x - x\rfloor \ge \lfloor3x \rfloor + \lfloor x\rfloor +\lfloor4x\rfloor -\lfloor x\rfloor \ge \lfloor3x\rfloor + \lfloor 4x\rfloor \ge \lfloor3x \rfloor + 2\lfloor2x\rfloor$$

But I don't know about this : $\lfloor4x - x\rfloor \ge \lfloor4x \rfloor - \lfloor x\rfloor.$ Am I right?

Comment: Try $x=\frac14$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen thanks a lot.

Comment: For what it is worth, $\lfloor 6x\rfloor$ entirely determines $\lfloor 3x\rfloor, \lfloor 2x\rfloor,$ and $\lfloor x\rfloor$, and the different can be evaluated on a case-by-case, based on $\lfloor 6x\rfloor\bmod 6$. So there should be a brute force proof.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is it possible to prove it using my idea? Or should I consider some intervals : $[0..1) $ and $[1..\infty]$?

Comment: It probably isn't going to work that way, @openspace

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I thought about mix this idea and consider partial points.

Comment: If $1/4$ is a counter-example, then $1+1/4$ si a counter-example, and $2+1/4$ is a counter-example, etc. In general, with "floor" questions, it doesn't help much to consider $(1,+\infty)$ separated, and you almost always want to considered just the case $x\in (0,1)$. But your approach isn't going to be useful in either interval, $(0,1)$ or $(1,+\infty)$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I understand that my proof is incorrect , but I guess that it's easy to prove : $\lfloor 3x \rfloor + \lfloor x \rfloor \ge 2\lfloor 2x \rfloor$

Comment: Except $\lfloor 3x\rfloor + \lfloor x\rfloor\geq 2\lfloor 2x\rfloor$ is not true. Try $x=1/2$. So it is not going to be easy to prove. @openspace

Comment: @ThomasAndrews what about this : consider $[0..\frac{1}{6}) \rightarrow 0 \ge 0$, then consider $[\frac{1}{6}..\frac{1}{3}) \rightarrow 1 \ge 0$ , then consider $[\frac{1}{3} .. \frac{1}{2}) \rightarrow 2 \ge 1$ , then consider $[\frac{1}{2} .. 1) \rightarrow (3,4,5) + 0 \ge (1,2) + 2 $, where $(3,4,5)$ are possible integers and $[6x] = 4 \rightarrow  x \ge \frac{2}{3} \rightarrow [3x] = 2$. Other points are useless, because integer part of equation isn't "interesting"?

Comment: Yes. I'd state it differently. Let $f(x)=\lfloor 6x\rfloor +\lfloor x\rfloor - 2\lfloor 2x\rfloor -\lfloor 3x\rfloor$. Then $f(x)$ is periodic - $f(x+1)=f(x)$ - so we only need to consider $x\in[0,1)$. Then show that $f(x)$ is constant on the interval $\left[\frac n6,\frac{n+1}6\right)$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$, so you only need to consider $x=\frac{n}{6}$ for $n=0,1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews thank you.