# Products of factorials and parentheses

Tags: notation

If I want to express "the product of $2n$ factorial and $3n$ factorial," is it clear enough to write $2n!3n!$, or is it necessary (or preferable) to write $(2n)!(3n)!$ for clarity?

The reason I ask is that there were no parentheses in the first expression [on this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956832/proof-of-lfloor-6n-rfloor-lfloor-n-rfloor-ge-2-lfloor-2n-rfloor-lflo) but no one seemed bothered.  Maybe the need for parentheses is context-dependent?

Comment: Generally I would prefer to disambiguate, unless the result is truly objectionable.

Comment: In your example the parentheses interpretation is the only reasonable one, because it is reasonable to expect the same notation on the two factors: either both have no parenthes or both have _omitted_ parentheses; since the former would simply have been written as $6(n!)^2$ or the same but with omitted parenthesis, it must be the latter. Instead, in $2n!n^n$ one will think that the parentheses were purposefully omitted, that is, the $2$ is outside the factorial. Context-dependent, but it's certainly preferable to use parentheses, and indeed it's formally the only way to go.

Comment: The lack of parenthesis in the question was an abuse but in discussing what the op had tried and the mere fact that there was any question at all ($\frac{6n!}{2n!2n!3n!} = \frac{1}{2(n!)^2}$-- what's the issue) it was clear and the people reading it just didn't notice, in the same sense one might not notice an obvious typo or incorrect punctuation mark.  It's pretty clear that by 2n! the op meant (2n!) but there is simply no way any consistent rules of notation can make that acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precedence of factorial is [higher](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Precedence.html) than of multiplication, thus

$$an! \neq (an)!$$